# How to use links in a bootstrap nav tab-pane?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I am having trouble with my links in a nav tab pane. For some reason the links are adding the domain name and then including the link in my href after like this:

[https://www.edmontonyouth.com/”www.edmontonyouth.com/attractions/edmonton-corn-maze”](https://www.edmontonyouth.com/%E2%80%9Dwww.edmontonyouth.com/attractions/edmonton-corn-maze%E2%80%9D)

What am I doing wrong?

If you'd like to check out the webpage I'm using on and see for yourself what it is doing you can find it on [www.edmontonyouth.com/places-to-visit-in-edmonton](http://www.edmontonyouth.com/places-to-visit-in-edmonton)

I am considering trying a list group instead to see if it works differently, since maybe the issue is that its a nav-pill.

Here is sample of my code:

```html
<div class="d-flex align-items-start">
  <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills me-3" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">
      Edmonton Corn Maze
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active text-center" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
      <img src="images/edmonton-corn-maze.jpg" class="mb-3" style="height: 200px" alt="The Edmonton Corn Maze photo" title="The Edmonton Corn Maze" />

      <p>
        The Edmonton Corn Maze is a great attraction for a day outside. The maze changes every year, but it has oh so much to do! There is stuff to do for the little and bigger kids, making it a great place for kids of all ages.
      </p>

      <a href="www.edmontonyouth.com/attractions/edmonton-corn-maze" class="btn btn-outline-primary me-2" title="The Edmonton Corn Maze" alt="The Edmonton Corn Maze Link">
        Link to our Review
      </a>

      <a href="https://www.edmontoncornmaze.ca/" class="btn btn-outline-primary" title="The Edmonton Corn Maze" alt="The Edmonton Corn Maze Link to Their Website">
        Link to Their Website
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are u using a full URL instead of a relative one as in images?

Comment: truthfully I have just gotten in the habit of using absolute links verse relative

Comment: Guys... you literally removed the problem from the code by editing it...

Answer (score 0):

Soo I just realized the problem was with the double quotes around my links. They were slightly different than the proper one for coding, as they are curved slightly (insert emoji with hand in face). I don't know how I managed that

Comment: Did you open the file with some "normal people editor" at some point? I know (for example) that the MacOS TextEdit likes to do that.

Comment: I do all my writing for the pages on a word document, and I usually put the url in there as well so I might have copied it from there with the quotes around it for some reason (I don't typically put the quotes in my word document but its possible I did out of habit). Otherwise I have no clue how that happened! I only use VS Code. Although that is good to know that I have to be very mindful of where I'm copying and pasting from because I have been trying to figure this out like most of the day today